# How to change the image size in a reusable component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my React Native application, I have a 48 x 48 profile picture component that is in the header on all of the screens.

**ProfilePicture.jsx**

```
const ProfilePicture = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Image style={styles.profPic} source={{ uri: userObj?.avatar }} />
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  profPic: {
    minHeight: 48,
    minWidth: 48,
    borderRadius: 100,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 2,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 1.0,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,

    elevation: 5,
  },
});

export default ProfilePicture;
```

Now, I want to use a larger version in my user settings screen where the user can change their profile image.

My thought was that by setting the style in the imported component, it would show a larger version of the image:

```
<ProfilePicture style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
```

However, the image remains the same size. I know I could just create another component with the required size for this page, but since the image comes from a remote server, I don't want to call the URL multiple times.

How can I do this just using my current component?

Comment: Why don’t you pass style as a prop? If you pass the style prop, use that, else use the default which is present in your ProfilePicture.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to handle this would be to pass in a `style` prop to your `ProfilePicture` component. That way any component using the `ProfilePicture` component would be able to overrule the default styling. Combine this with the fact that the `style` prop of react-native components can take in arrays as value, and the code is pretty clean

```
const ProfilePicture = ({ style }) => {
  return (
    <Image style={[styles.profPic, style]} source={{ uri: userObj?.avatar }} />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  profPic: {
    minHeight: 48,
    minWidth: 48,
    borderRadius: 100,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 2,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 1.0,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,

    elevation: 5,
  },
});

export default ProfilePicture;
```

Your example code will then work as intended

```
<ProfilePicture style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. I was still a bit stuck trying to do this but your solution worked.